# xml transforming

Tags: xml

```
  <Products>    
    <Product ProductID="1">
      <productName>Ball</productName>
      <Color>Green</Color>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductID="2">
      <productName>Doll</productName>
      <Color>White</Color>
    </Product>      
  </Products>
```

I have an xml input like above.But i have problem in creating the product element that have the product name as attribute and the product id as the element under product.below is the code that i have.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="//Products">
 <html>
  <body>
   <Products>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Product">
     <xsl:call-template name="Import"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </Products>
  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template name="Import" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do it in a following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="//Products">
        <html>
            <body>
                <Products>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </Products>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:element name="product">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="ProductName/text()" />
            <xsl:element name="productID">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ProductID" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Btw, you have a small error in input XML (`productName` doesn't have a capital letter)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="//Products">
 <html>
  <body>
   <Products>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Product">
     <xsl:call-template name="Import"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </Products>
  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>
```

into

```
<xsl:template match="Products">
 <html>
  <body>
   <Products>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </Products>
  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>
```

then write a template

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
  <product name="{ProductName}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@ProductID"/>
  </product>
</xsl:template>
```

and a template

```
<xsl:template match="Product/@ProductID">
  <productID>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </productID>
</xsl:template>
```